# Finding the value of double derivative of function with given information

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non constant, three times differentiable function. If given that, $f(1+\frac{1}{n})=1$ for all the integers $n$. Then, find $f''(1)$.

One way I thought about it, by differentiating the expression with respect to n but that didn't not make sense because it yields a value of minus one and positive one of n. Please help. How can I compute this. Thanks in advance.